# NodeJS - why the infinite loop is not infiniting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have this following infinite loop but only after 2 attempt, it does not anymore continue executing `run_click()`;

[image]

How can i fix it, to let run forever without getting block?

```
var forever = null;

function loopit() {
    forever = setTimeout(function() {
      run_click();
      loopit(); // Please run for-ever to keep alive the robot
    }, 5000);   
}

function run_click()  {
  var robot = require("robotjs");
  var mouse=robot.getMousePos();
  // 2 time it shows on the console but then nothing...
  console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);
  robot.moveMouse(770,442);
  robot.mouseClick();
  robot = null;  
}

loopit();
```

Comment: are you sure it's not executing? console log the date at the top of `loopit` to be sure

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/yhb2fot3/)

Comment: Possible some exception in robotjs?

Comment: http://imgur.com/CrOIPmV - please see after the mouseClick() function it hang there, until manually CTRL+C is send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works. BUG in NodeJS (robotjs). Use other tools.

[image]